# Hyperledger Fabric deploy new chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm using the following code to setup sample hyperledger fabric project. https://github.com/hyperledger/education/tree/master/LFS171x

The chaincode is written at `fabric-material/chaincode/tuna-app/tuna-chaincode.go` , what should i do if i want to write a new chaincode with different functionalities? What is the use of property `chaincodeId` in the `request` variable which is passed to `channel.sendTransactionProposal`

Comment: You can write chaincode to implement any business logic. And then you can choose to deploy the chaincode from various ways like, java sdk, node sdk, fabric-tool cli to deploy the chaincode and test them..CaincodeId is an object which contain, chaincode related things like chaincode name , its path and version. With this chaincode name , ledger will be created.

Comment: I'm using node sdk, If i write a new chaincode under chanicode/tuna-app folder how should i call it from front end?

Comment: Will it compile all files listed inside chaincode/tuna-app folder?

Comment: first of all you need to see from which path your sdk is picking to deploy your code. You can have n number of go files in that folder but keep only one main method. That file which have main method will be picked as a stating point and deploy all your go code. For compiling try to issue go build command, make sure you have all the shim libraries in gopath.